# Re-linking mesh data while adjusting object transform to undo minor edit-mode tweaks

Tags: modeling, scripting, mesh, objects, transforms

Let's say I have a set of meshes that I duplicated with Shift-D and then distributed around the scene. And then for some reason I accidentally manipulated some of them in edit mode rather than object mode.

I then decide I'd like to go back and relink the object data and woogh, I have to figure out how the heck to match a new object transform to where the old mesh was.

Considering that the mesh still has 99%+ of it's bounding box / median point / vertex distribution type stuff in the same shape, if not the same place, is there any means, method, script, or other facility to compare these and correct the receiving object's object-space parameters to apply the other mesh to it but remain in the same physical space?

---

Update ~

So, I ended up solving my original problems, which were all translation based, by setting all of the object's origins to geometry / center of mass with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, and then doing the dirty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> business.

I'm still curious if it's feasable to fix rotations, given that the objects all have basically identical meshes. Say, I have this case, where the objects were shift-D duplicated and then for some reason had their rotation applied. Say, in this example:

[image: Before relink]

Relinking the objects to one mesh does this:

[image]

It seems like it should be possible to automatically recreate the rotations during relinking, given that the meshes and centers are identical, but I wouldn't even know where to begin with doing that.

*(Also, if anyone's wondering what they're looking at, that's what happens when I give myself 60 seconds to make 'something vaguely like a spanner')*

Comment: When you moved the meshes in the first place, were you in _object mode_, or _edit mode_?

Comment: I'm pretty sure linking object data (ctrl-L + `Object Data`) doesn't affect the object transforms. So I wonder if the mesh data relative to its origin is different for each object.. What happens if you hit Transform->Object->Origin to Geometry for each object, before linking their mesh data?

Comment: Just select all, then search 'set origin'. Select origin to geometry. it puts all of the origins back to the center of the objects.

Comment: Remove the update and add it as an answer.