# Do not rotate when linking objects

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, linked-data

I imported a file that was created by another program. At one point, It has a large group of identical components, but they are not linked together. I know I can press `Ctrl-L` to link them, but when I select object data, they are all rotated to align with each other (not preserving current rotation). How might I fix it so that they do that.

[Re-linking mesh data while adjusting object transform to undo minor edit-mode tweaks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19523/re-linking-mesh-data-while-adjusting-object-transform-to-undo-minor-edit-mode-tw) seems to have a simmilar issue, but his fix did not work for me.

Comment: There is really no easy way to fix it other than manually one-by-one, or re-importing with different settings- Where was this imported from, a CAD file? Try using blocks for each object instead

Comment: No can do. It is a dae I pulled from the sketchup warehouse. Oh well.